# how to merge data in multiple rows into one row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Here is an example of how the data looks, and how I would like it to look

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a macro

```
Sub Flatten_em()

Dim inRow, outRow, outCol As Integer
Dim CheckVal As String

inRow = 3
outRow = 2

Sheets(1).Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(2).Select
Rows("1:1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets(1).Select
CheckVal = Cells(2, 2)

Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 7)).Select
Selection Copy
Sheets(2).Select
Cells(outRow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Do Until Cells(inRow, 2) = ""
    outCol = 8
    Do While Cells(inRow, 2) = CheckVal
        Sheets(1).Select
        Range(Cells(inRow, 4), Cells(inRow, 7)).Select
        Sheets(2).Select
        Cells(outRow, outCol).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        outCol = outCol + 4
        inRow = inRow + 1
    Loop
    CheckVal = Sheets(1).Cells(inRow, 2)
    outRow = outRow + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the Formula `CONCATENATE`

For example to merge A3, B3, C3, D3, E3, F3, G3 into the merged cell do the following:

Within the merged cell type the below formula

```
=CONCATENATE(A3,B3,c3,D3,E3,F3,G3)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what they want to do.

Comment: Thank you but that is not what I am looking for. I don't want to create one cell. I want to take the duplicate codes in D, E, F, and G and move to the end of the first occurrence of the PLI. Cell B is the unique identifier. Is there a way to do this?